# How can I sanitize custom CSS, without it breaking?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In my Wordpress theme I'm allowing custom CSS to be entered within the Theme Customiser, in the form of a text area field.

Naturally, I want to apply some sanitation to this input, but when I use the regular `esc_textarea`, it breaks some CSS rules that include `>` symbols, converting these into HTML entities.

My question is, how can I safely sanitise the input, without changing the CSS rules as they are typed?

```
if(!function_exists('psychic2016_add_customCSS')) {
    function psychic2016_add_customCSS() {
        echo '<style id="psychic2016-custom-css">'.esc_textarea(get_theme_mod('psychic2016_customCSS')).'</style>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'psychic2016_add_customCSS', 1000);
```

Comment: Quickfix : Add `'.str_replace(array('&gt;','&lt;'),array('>','<'),esc_textarea(`

Comment: `safely sanitise` You can allways use first `strip_tags()` before using `str_replace(...,esc_textar‌ea` because HTML-Tags are not allowed in CSS.

Comment: The Doc say `Encodes text for use inside a <textarea> element.` so you use this function at the wrong place i thing. You have to sanitise by yourself.